# Is there a limit to DecodeBase64 from EncdDecd?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there a limit on how large of a Base64 string you can pass in?

I'm using the following and when my image gets created it's missing a portion of the bottom. I see that BufferLen is ~44000 and yet DecodeBase64 returns about an array of about 24000 items.

```
BufferLen := (Length(JVal) * 4) div 3;
SetLength(PtrB, BufferLen);
PtrB := DecodeBase64(AnsiString(JVal));

JStream := TStringStream.Create(PtrB);
Jpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
Jpeg.LoadFromStream(JStream);
Self.JPG := Jpeg;
```

Comment: Which Delphi version? Presumably >= 2009 because of the AnsiString conversion.

Comment: When you set the length of `PtrB`, the string you allocate is ultimately discarded without ever being used. You assign a completely new value to that variable after you call `DecodeBase64`. That means your `BufferLen` calculation is never really used, either. And why is `Temp` in this code? What is `JVal`, and why does it need to be type-cast to `AnsiString`?

Comment: Delphi XE2, and I removed Temp as that was for debugging oops! JVal is a string coming in, encoded as Base64, so it probably would be OK without being typecast.

Comment: Why are you using `DecodeBase64` rather than `DecodeString`?

Comment: What is the point of the `SetLength`? You can simply remove that. And why pass a `TBytes` to a string stream. Don't you mean `TBytesStream`?

Comment: TStringStream for binary data is not a good idea. Most likely image is cut because of CR/LF symbol somewhere in base64-decoded data.

Comment: Careful with that unit. It is undocumented and obsolete: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=84476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no size limitation on the code in the Soap.EncdDecd unit, beyond that imposed by the use of the `AnsiString` data type.

This program which successfully encodes and then decodes a 100MB string demonstrates the point:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Soap.EncdDecd;

var
  i: Integer;
  plain, encoded: string;

begin
  SetLength(plain, 100*1024*1024);
  for i := 1 to Length(plain) do
    plain[i] := Chr(32+Random(80));
  encoded := EncodeString(plain);
  if plain=DecodeString(encoded) then
    Writeln('passed')
  else
    Writeln('failed');
  Readln;
end.
```

Your problem almost certainly lies in your code rather than the `EncdDecd` unit.

You code could be quite a bit simpler. For example:

```
JStream := TBytesStream.Create(DecodeBase64(JVal));
Jpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
Jpeg.LoadFromStream(JStream);
```

Comment: I believe I found it. I changed my encoding to use EncodeString instead of EncodeBase64 and passed in a string instead of an ansistring. Now my picture has all its data. So I'm inclined to think it was the AnsiString limitation.