# Load bitmap into TWebbrowser

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Does anyone know of a way to load a bitmap image into a `TWebBrowser` component?

I've never attempted it before, not entirely sure where to begin if possible.

Comment: I removed the twebbrowser tag since that refers to the VCL component. Doesn't `TWebBrowser` render web pages?  If you want to display a bitmap isn't that the wrong component?

Comment: Navigate to file://path_to_bitmap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode your bitmap with base64 (I think you can find online converters), then create a tag like this :

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,BASE64DATAGOESHERE..." width="100" height="100" />
```

Embed this line into an Html tag and then use Webbrowser.LoadFromStrings

or use file:/// url

Comment: This control has no `LoadFromString` method: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser_Methods  Are you quite sure that `image/bmp` is correct for the FMX web browser?

Comment: it was loadfromstrings, I correcred it. as for image/bmp why not?  he can use data:image/png instead.

Comment: Whilst Pascal is not sensitive to case, surely you would not actually write `loadfromstrings` in code. Surely you'd respect the capitalization. On the other hand, it doesn't look like you are keen on using upper case in your writing. Sentences should start with a capital. And "u" is not a word.

Comment: I am also about transcoding to png or gif. Additionally is FMX browser yet another wrapper over MSIE like VCL browser? Because many MSIE versions do not support data-URI at all, others only support data-URI with text size less than 64KB // maybe some native Delphi HTML renderer would do the job better, though implanting VCL components into FMX form is another can of worms

Comment: also I think he does not have to use stand-alone (online) base64 converters (though it is an option, and may even be version-control friendly) because it would make editing those pictures harder. He can well keep them binary in his project and convert to base64 in runtime - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15936393/976391